# Anyone have a moment to offer some critique?

Tags: critique, sound-design, sound-effects, creature-vocalizations

Hello Sound Designers!  I added a sound to the SSD Soundcloud group that I'd like some feedback from. It's the one titled "monster".

I haven't done creature effects before, so I started messing around with some sounds.  I got something that, to me, sounds monster-like but I'd really like some "pro" ears on it.

I did another version with reverb and such, and got so many different opinions as to what to sound actually was I decided to re-tweak it.  (grand dad said it sounded like something falling down)

I'm not sensitive, and find negative feedback helpful so if all you have to say is negative I'd really like to hear it.  I hope to have a good skill-set someday =)

Comment: File/player/video?

Comment: I'm going to comment since I'm not a "Pro" (Yet haha), it's kind of cool, sounds like some sort of little robot dying to me and I think that's cause of the lack of low end. It doesn't have have much power and size to it if that make sense. Try doing some vocalizations it feels totally retarded but fun, keep a glass of water beside you haha.

Comment: With your own voice*

Comment: @g.a.harry it's just audio - http://soundcloud.com/aross001/monster

@stephen cool! I didn't think of that.  As for size, I should probably find some short video or at least a picture of the monster I'm trying to "give voice" to.  That would probably be more meaningful.


Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a big snore! Although it is cool, like Stephen said above, it doesn't have much power neither the sound seemed to have good definition.
I don't know how you did it, but human laughs and even the most hysterical screams are cool to work on, playing their pitch, length, and vocoder works for the best!

Comment: I'll give that a try, I'll admit I spent alot more time on higher frequency stuff.  I wanted something that "rattled" a bit. I didn't really think about how big the monster was I was giving a voice to, so I think I'll put some thought into that as well as I work on the low end.